# How to clean unused homebrew dependencies

Tags: macos, homebrew

How to remove all homebrew packages wich are not used by any other package?
Some packages are installed as dependency of other package. When packages are removed, dependent packages stay as leftovers.

`apt` support the `autoremove` command for example. Is there such command in hombrew?

Answer (score 125, accepted):

You can get rid of all unused dependencies using `brew autoremove` in HomeBrew versions 2.5.9 and above.

The autoremove functionality was added in [this](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/commit/0fa417706a2143dbec1e6fd2f29f3e3e32663252#diff-edb875c29770ac7b97c8ccc595daa8e064ac72db6beff490cff3a425d5151453) commit on 5 Nov 2020.

Comment: This also removes some packages that are listed in brewfile, why is that?

Answer (score 57):

Found on linuxbrew issue

```
brew bundle dump
brew bundle --force cleanup
```

`brew` now supports `Brewfiles`. `brew bundle dump` generates a `Brewfile` with all the packages installed by user. Dependent packages are not listed here

example:

```
brew "python3"
brew "curl"
brew "tmux"
brew "neovim"
```

This file can be used to install the same software automatically. But also for doing a cleanup of unused packages. Edit the file then keep only the packages you need. Then run `brew bundle --force cleanup`. It will remove everything not listed or depending on the packages in the file.

WARNING: Also not listed casks will be removed