# How to keep Homebrew apps clean and current - How to find installed apps no longer used

Tags: macos, homebrew

How do I know if I can or should clean up anything? I have a ton of installed apps, and a brew update takes forever.

I'd like to at least find which apps I no longer use.

I did `brew autoremove`, [one question here](https://superuser.com/questions/1509212/how-to-clean-unused-homebrew-dependencies), and it found and removed a couple files, but no noticeable difference in `brew update`.

I can `brew list`, but so many of them are libraries, and there are so many of them, that I don't really want to do `brew info app` on each of them.  Surely there's a way to tell the difference between apps that I installed vs libraries?

Answer (score 1):

A Perl script to get Access times of the target of the links placed in /usr/local/bin.  Then it shows the oldest-accessed files last.

But I don't know if this is the best answer, or if there's something that can be done in homebrew.  I don't even know if this is necessary - is speeding up the upgrade process possible?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# Looking for old homebrew apps to get rid of

use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Spec;
use POSIX qw(strftime);

my $dir = '/usr/local/bin';

my @sorted_by_oldest_used =
    sort { $b->[2] <=> $a->[2] }
    map {
        my $t = readlink;
        $t = "$dir/$t" if not File::Spec->file_name_is_absolute($t);
        $t =~ /Cellar|Cask/ ? [ $_, $t, -A $t ] : ()
    }
    grep { -l }
    glob "$dir/*";

foreach my $res_ar (reverse @sorted_by_oldest_used) {
    my $date = strftime("%Y_%m_%d_%H:%M:%S", localtime(time - $res_ar->[2] * 24 * 60 * 60));
    printf "%s\t%s\n", $date, $res_ar->[0];
}
```

Code credit: [Stackoverflow question I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77821258/how-do-i-find-the-oldest-used-files-from-a-program-that-links-its-bins-like-hom/77821377), with a better response than the script I came up with.